# How to connect on premise Kubernetes to google cloud VPN

Tags: kubernetes, cloud, vpn, hybrid

I'm trying to create a hybrid VPN connection.  I want to connect my google cloud GKE cluster with my on premise Kubernetes cluster using a VPN.  I want to develop on premise pods that communicate with google cluster through the VPN as if it is on the cloud.  I created a Classic VPN on google cloud(many instructions for that).  I am using WSL2 but would take any advice for Linux as well.  How do I create a VPN gateway in Kubernetes on my local machine to connect to my google cloud classic VPN gateway with just one tunnel?  Is there a docker or helm chart for this?

Tried searching for solutions, but they only explained the google cloud configurations.  They left the Linux/Kubernetes explanations out and left it to on site it/router expertise, perhaps because it is obvious.

Comment: I believe there are many people who want to use basic infrastructure on the cloud, but also leverage their own hardware on premise so I am very surprised this exact solution has not been brought up many times.  I'm not a network expert but this is a desirable solution I think.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/anthos/clusters/docs/bare-metal/latest/how-to/network-connectivity-gateway

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to connect to your workloads which are on a public cloud(here GCP) first you need to make necessary configurations on both sides i.e you should configure a network peering. GCP has provided many references on such architectures.

you can use the document given by `Harsh Manvar` as a reference since you are working on kubernetes clusters

> https://cloud.google.com/anthos/clusters/docs/bare-metal/latest/how-to/network-connectivity-gateway

There is one more tutorial available for compute engine go through this [link](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/tutorials/configure-vpn-between-onprem-cloud) for more information.

Comment: @robertcrowder is your issue resolved revert back if you are still facing the issues.